# Are there any way to parallelize independent for loop inside kernel for CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I am trying to parallelize for loop inside kernel for CUDA. For example, here is a simple example kernel:

```
__global__ void sample_kernel(int n, float *x, float *y) {
  for (int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; i < n; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        y[10 * i + j] = j * x[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Since loop for `j` is independent, I want to parallelize this loop too. Are there any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CUDA, threads execute work. An instruction is issued to a warp of threads, which in the case of CUDA comprises of 32 threads. This means that in theory you can parallelize pretty much any code you want within the limits of the hardware.

In your case, the way you're doing this now is that a thread executes the grid-stride for the outer loop and for each iteration of the outer loop every iteration of the inner loop.

The standard way of doing what you're trying to accomplish as long as you have no more than three nested loops is to take advantage of the fact that the grid is three dimensional in CUDA (although you can use a 1D grid) and to do a nested grid-stride:

```
__global__ void sample_kernel(int n, float *x, float *y) {
  for (int i = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; i < n; i += blockDim.y * gridDim.y) {
    for (int j = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; j < 10; j += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
        y[10 * i + j] = j * x[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, this isn't the only way of doing it: you can achieve the same effect with a one dimensional grid. For this, you just have to split the work differently instead of doing the regular grid-stride.